# Tableau - Find median of top 10 in a category

Tags: tableau-desktop

Based on my data, I want to find the median PRICE of top 10 IDs basis the ENR value in every county. In the attached file

[image: 1]

I have already found the top 10 IDs basis the ENR value but cannot figure out how to find the median of these top 10 PRICE values in a county.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [this](https://www.datameer.com/blog/tableau_how-would-you-calculate-the-median-of-a-dataset-in-the-table-in-excel-it-would-have-been-an-array-formula-is-there-a-way-to-replicate-it-in-tableau/) might help